# xib can not load the image resource from a bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, resources, bundle, xib

OK.Here is the situation.I think it is strange.I can not figure out what is wrong.

I create a static library project.And in that project I create a bundle named Common to put the image resources.

And I have 2 app project. One for ipad and the other one is for iphone.And in both app project I drag the bundle to it.So the both app project can use the image resource from the bundle Common.

For example, I put a png named clock.png in the bundle Common.In the ipad app project I create a login.xib,and in the xib there is a UIImageView which I select the clock.png as its image.The clock.png can be seen in the xib.I do the same thing in the iphone app project.

the strange thing is when I run the ipad app.The clock.png image can be load and shown on the screen.But when it comes to the iphone app, it says "Could not load the "clock.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "xx" ".

I am very confused about this.As I see, there no much difference between the two app project.Is there any settings that I should add?

Comment: try removing old and adding a new UIImageView for the iphone XIB embedding the same clock.png

Comment: It did not work.I think the problem is there is some special settings for the app project.There is nothing to do with the certain xib or UIImageview.@AppleDelegate

Comment: ==> check below post link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664964/use-images-on-asset-catalog-in-interface-builder