# Use images on Asset Catalog in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode5, asset-catalog

Is it possible to use the images added to Assets Catalog directly on interface builder?
How is that done?

On UIImageView properties I can't see any option to reference any image on assets catalog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Import the images into the `.xcassets` folder

   - click the '+' in the bottom right, 'Import folder'
2. Setup each image with its 1x and 2x image size
3. Give it a name

Images can then be referenced programmatically with `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"some-image"]`, or via the image dropdown in IB/Storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

All of the images in an asset catalog have a name. This name can be used in `imageNamed:` and in IB.